# wireless not working

Tags: 12.10, intel-wireless

i have a dell laptop .
i have installed ubuntu 12.10 .
i m not able to get corrected to wifi .
its not detecting any wireless drivers .
i hv tried download many packages fronm software center but no use .
n so is the problem with bluetooth . its written searchin devices . bt it is not detecting the device .
my friend has also installed the same software with hp laptop and hhhe is able to access wireless directly .
kindly help .

Comment: To enable us to give you more useful answers, please edit your question by running `lspci | grep Network` command in a terminal and adding the results.

Comment: Also, output of `ip a` might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

At Ubuntu dashboard( press window key ) search Additional Drivers , and it will search drivers for Wifi and more graphics driver , you can select first "Broadcom STA wireless driver" and install it and for more graphics also install ATI/AMD graphics driver.

Also try to visit this video to install driver:- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lsbUO_8MFfA

after install restart the Ubuntu . and

some times it will first time not search the wifi devise so sleep the pc for 1 min. and login again(but its rare case).